# U-Boot --building uImage Minnowboard

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

I am working on an embedded project to optimize the boot time on minnowboard.
Currently I am working with the u-boot. With compressed kernel
(bzImage) everything works fine, I want to check the performance with
uncompressed kernel (vmlinux).

I read that u-boot cannot support the raw vmlinux and I need to
generate the uImage using the u-boot tools.

I tried creating the uImage from the vmlinux --but I did not
understand what does the -a (load address) and -e (entry point )
points to? I assume that it is the same load address used when loading
the kernel image from sd card to RAM.

```
uImage creation:

mkimage -A x86 -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x01000000 -e 0x01000000 -n Linux -d vmlinux uImage
Image Name:   Linux
Created:      Wed Jun 22 17:03:17 2016
Image Type:   Intel x86 Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    21966248 Bytes = 21451.41 kB = 20.95 MB
Load Address: 01000000
Entry Point:  01000000
```

Now at start up I am seeing that the kernel is not running, with the
following error messages,

```
reading uImage
21966312 bytes read in 481 ms (43.6 MiB/s)
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

The bootcmd is

```
"bootcmd=fatload mmc 0:1 01000000 uImage ; bootm 01000000"
```

Do you have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: You need to use `Image` file, it's actually uncompressed kernel file, not `vmlinux`.

Comment: SamProtsenko : Ok I will try with the image file, but do you have any idea what is the load address and entry point corresponds to , when building the uImage

Comment: It means exactly what it states: **load address** is an address in the memory to which the image will be loaded, **entry point** is the address to where boot loader jumps.

Comment: @evk1206 I believe Wolfgang Denk gave you a perfect detailed explanation of load address [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/u-boot@lists.denx.de/msg216985.html).